# Define the first line of file as a header to use in the rest of the file NODEJS

Tags: node.js, fs, readline

I'v to read a file into a array multidimensional, so I can manipulate it. I'm doing this with readline, but how could I get the first line and define it as the header and skip it from the rest. Follows mycode:

```
const fields = []
        const fileData = []

        rl.on('line', (line)=>{
            const rowData = line.split(delimiter)
            for (let index = 0; index < header.length; index++) {
                fields[header[index]] = rowData[index]                         
            }
            fileData.push(fields)
        })
```

The array header is what I need, but I can't think how. I tried something inside the event "on", like:

```
  const header = []
  if(!header){
    header = line.split(delimiter)
  }
```

But, didn't work :S

Some help, please?

Answer (score 0):

I get it!

I had justo to change const header to let header.

Thanks!